# laravel get after 5 hour data

Tags: php, database, laravel

Hello this is my laravel project where i want to get data what is older then 5 hours. How can i do this please give me a solution.
Thanks

```
    $date = new \DateTime();
    $date->modify('6 hours');
    $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    if (Auth::user()->role == 'seller'){
        $orders = Order::where('seller_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', '0')->get();
    }
    if (Auth::user()->role == 'curier'){
        $orders = Order::where('curier_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', '0')->get();
    }
    if (Auth::user()->role == 'superadmin' || Auth::user()->role == 'manager'){
        $orders = Order::where('status', '0')->get();
    }
    return view($this->view_page_url.'ready_ship', compact('orders'));`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datas that older then 5 hours, so its `created_at` is less than 5 hours ago.

You can use `Carbon::now()->subHours(5)` to get the time,

and then get the datas:

```php
$datetime = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subHours(5)->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if (Auth::user()->role == 'seller'){
    $orders = Order::where('seller_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', '0');
}
if (Auth::user()->role == 'curier'){
    $orders = Order::where('curier_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('status', '0');
}
if (Auth::user()->role == 'superadmin' || Auth::user()->role == 'manager'){
   $orders = Order::where('status', '0');
}

$orders = $orders->where('created_at', '<=', $datetime)->get();
```